# I am having troubles installing node dependencies on a cloned React project. How do I solve this?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

I have a project I am working on, I add to the code and commit from a window 10 PC. Now I tried cloning the project from an ubuntu OS and it keeps giving me the `CODE FETCH ERROR` when I tried installing the Node modules.

I have tried running `npm cache clean --force` before the `npm install` command, problem persists. I also tried updating node package manager. :(

````
npm WARN tarball tarball data for commander@https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-2.20.3.tgz (sha512-GpVkmM8vF2vQUkj2LvZmD35JxeJOLCwJ9cUkugyk2nuhbv3+mJvpLYYt+0+USMxE+oj+ey/lJEnhZw75x/OMcQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
npm WARN tarball tarball data for react-dom@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom/-/react-dom-17.0.2.tgz (sha512-s4h96KtLDUQlsENhMn1ar8t2bEa+q/YAtj8pPPdIjPDGBDIVNsrD9aXNWqspUe6AzKCIG0C1HZZLqLV7qpOBGA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tar zlib: unexpected end of file
npm WARN tarball tarball data for node-sass@https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sass/-/node-sass-6.0.1.tgz (sha512-f+Rbqt92Ful9gX0cGtdYwjTrWAaGURgaK5rZCWOgCNyGWusFYHhbqCCBoFBeat+HKETOU02AyTxNhJV0YZf2jQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tar zlib: unexpected end of file
npm WARN tarball tarball data for node-notifier@https://registry.npmjs.org/node-notifier/-/node-notifier-8.0.2.tgz (sha512-oJP/9NAdd9+x2Q+rfphB2RJCHjod70RcRLjosiPMMu5gjIfwVnOUGq2nbTjTUbmy0DJ/tFIVT30+Qe3nzl4TJg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tar zlib: unexpected end of file
npm WARN tarball tarball data for iconv-lite@https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.4.24.tgz (sha512-v3MXnZAcvnywkTUEZomIActle7RXXeedOR31wwl7VlyoXO4Qi9arvSenNQWne1TcRwhCL1HwLI21bEqdpj8/rA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for execa@https://registry.npmjs.org/execa/-/execa-4.1.0.tgz (sha512-j5W0//W7f8UxAn8hXVnwG8tLwdiUy4FJLcSupCg6maBYZDpyBvTApK7KyuI4bKj8KOh1r2YH+6ucuYtJv1bTZA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tar zlib: unexpected end of file
npm WARN tar zlib: unexpected end of file
npm WARN tarball tarball data for eventsource@https://registry.npmjs.org/eventsource/-/eventsource-1.1.0.tgz (sha512-VSJjT5oCNrFvCS6igjzPAt5hBzQ2qPBFIbJ03zLI9SE0mxwZpMw6BfJrbFHm1a141AavMEB8JHmBhWAd66PfCg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tar zlib: unexpected end of file
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-2.20.3.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kingslee/.npm/_logs/2021-11-05T22_56_01_013Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Try to remove package-lock.json and remove node_modules, then npm install again